# Need for pulsed laser

Tags: electromagnetism, laser

Pulsed laser emit light in non continuous mode.How this makes it superior to cw laser? Why there is need in reducing the time-lag between the pluses of pulsed laser.

Comment: It is unclear that you are asking. Please rephrase you question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will briefly explain the lasers and pulsed lasers.

**Lasers:** As you know lasers are coherent source of radiation. When light is passed from a normal medium it get absorbed due to the fact that most of the atoms are in ground state, if by some means we can place most of the atoms in excited state (known as population inversion) then the passage of light result in its amplification (this type of medium is known as active medium). In lasers we exactly follow this approach and amplify the light. In this manner laser make a coherent light source. To put the medium into population inversion we need some sort of external excitation (electrical, optical or chemical, commonly termed as pumping of the medium). Wavelength of the laser ranges from Far infra red to ultraviolet regime. With this background I will now explain the pulsed lasers.

One can theoretically make the short pulse lasers by simply chopping the CW laser beams but in this way we will significantly loose the energy of the laser beam, Hence other techniques to generate pulse lasers is used.

**Advantage of pulsed lasers:** The pulsed lasers can have much higher peak powers. Today it is possible to make the lasers with pulsed powers exeeding petawatts ($10^{15}$ watts of durations $25-100$ femtoseonds). We can make lasers of duration as small as $5$ fs commercially (however the power is small ~$1nj$ per pulse).

very short duration of laser pulses can be treated as short flashes and can help us capture the snapshots of basic atomic processes. To understand their role suppose you have a camera with shutter speed 1 second and you want to take photo with it now if you are in a dark room and create a flash of $1 \mu s$, you will get the snapshot of very small duration. Just imagine what will happen if the duration of the flash is femtoseonds.

Pulsed lasers can be subdivided into three categories.

**1. Long laser pulses** : These are commercial grade lasers, the duration of these lasers is limited by the duration of the pumping source (ranges in milisecond to $\mu s$). These lasers are widely used in laser cutting drilling and laser based prototyping.

**2. Short laser pulses**: The duration of these type of lasers is in the range of picoseconds to nanoseconds. These lasers are used in the generatin of high temperature plasma, for Inertial confinement fusion and other pump probe studies (to probe rotational and vibrational energy levels). World's biggest lasers (such as National Ignition Facility NIF) falls in this category.

**3. Ultrashort laser pulses**: Broadly lasers with pulse duration <100 femtoseond falls in this category. These pulses are very short and can catpure very fast events such as electronic transfer. Moreover they can have very high powers ($>10^{15}$ W), upon focusing the electric field of these lasers can easily exceed atomic field, Hence very interesting nonlinear processes can be observed with these lasers. Try to read about, electron acceleration, Ion acceleration, High order harmonic generation using ultrashort laser pulses.

These laser pulses can be used to generate world's fastest light events i.e.attosecond ($10^{-18}$s) pulses, which can probe extremely fast events such as electron tunelling dynamics, ionization dynamics, Photoelectron emission dynamics.

With this explanation you will now get a glimpse of the usage of pulsed lasers. CW lasers are also developing in terms of power and energy but they are now at back seat. CW laser are mostly used for pumping the active medium to generate high rep rate (MHz) pulsed lasers.

Thank you for your patience

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

It is not a matter of being superior. The pulsed laser and the CW laser have different applications. The reason for using pulsed lasers is that if the time interval is very small you can probe events in nature on very small time scales. You can also examine aspects of quantum mechanics, for if the time interval of a laser pulse is very small the Heisenberg uncertainty principle then dictates the spread in energy is very large.

A laser is close to being a pure form of light, but it does not have exactly a single frequency. This is particularly the case if you have pulsed lasers. A CW laser beam is close to having the idea of a single wavelength or frequency, for the time baseline of a CW laser is very large and so the uncertainty in frequency is very small. With $\Delta\nu\Delta t~\sim~1$, and since energy is $E~=~h\nu$. the connection to the Heisenberg uncertainty principle is clear. The pulsed laser in a cavity or an interferometer have longitudinal modes that fit within the confined high Q system. One then gets a set of modes that are recurrent in the cavity, which is called mode locking.

An example of an application with pulsed laser is quantum tomography. With pulsed lasers you can take snap shots of atoms and their electronic configurations. With a succession of such snap shots one can construct a picture of an atom or molecule. In addition with chemistry, pulsed lasers permit snap shots of atoms and molecules during chemical changes. It is possible to then to construct the dynamics of a chemical change in time, much like a form of quantum tomography, but where the snap shots occur at different times in a chemical change.

I am not going to say this is practical, but in principle with hypershort laser pulses we could probe physics of elementary particles. Femtosecond pulsed lasers at $10^{-15}$sec is by $c~=~\delta\lambda\delta\nu$ means the region probed is on the order of $3\times 10^{-5}$ cm. With several orders of magnitude shorter pulses, such as in the attosecond range $10^{-18}$sec, we can probe distances down to the atom. If by various means we could get pulses a million times smaller the nucleus could be probed. Further down a billion time shorter pulse would allow us to probe the structure of hadrons in the same way we now probe atoms with pulsed lasers. That is something to think about, but the technical problems are formidable. This also includes fundamental time limits for the QED interaction.

Comment: Another application is the generation of intense fields to induce nonlinear effects such as frequency doubling.  Some specialized clocks use pulsed lasers